# Does Quote have CurrencyIsoCode field?

Tags: standard-objects, quote, standard-field

In the Quote Standard Fields (Setup > Customize > Quotes > Fields) there is no CurrencyIsoCode field. However, when I run the following apex code:

```
List<Quote> quotes = [SELECT Id, Name, CurrencyIsoCode FROM Quote LIMIT 1];
System.debug('>>> quotes: ' + quotes);
```

I can see CurrencyIsoCode:

> 16:55:42:004 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT
>   [25]|quotes|[{"Id":"0Q00m000000Cl4KCAS","Name":"Test_20170623",**"CurrencyIsoCode":"EUR"**,"RecordTypeId":"012610000002iLVAAY"}]|0x4da9e55a

No clue on the CurrencyIsoCode field of the Quote object in this [help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=quotes_fields.htm&siteLang=en_US&type=0) either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have answered your own question. The [`SOAP API Developer Guide`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_quote.htm) also lists this field.

> ### CurrencyIsoCode
>
> **Type**
>   picklist
>
> **Properties**
>   Defaulted on create, Filter, Restricted picklist
>
> **Description**
>   Available only for organizations with the multicurrency feature enabled. Contains the ISO code for any currency allowed by the organization.
>   If the organization has multicurrency and a Pricebook2Id specified on the quote, then the currency value of this field must match the currency of the PricebookEntry objects that are associated with any quote line items it has.
>   This value is copied from the related Opportunity and can't be changed.

Comment: Thank you, Adrian. I missed to check that part of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Should currencyisocode be mapped automatically froom Opportunity to Quote in CPQ ?
I mean, always. Not only in primary quote.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/206499)